# AWS Cognito - Creating pools using Cloud Formation - Expected supported properties returning as unsupported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I am attempting to create Cognito pools as part of the Serverless framework, using yaml configuration. I have an object, with a root properties including `VerificationMessageTemplate` and `UsernameAttributes`

However, I receive the error message `An error occurred: RequesterPool - Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [VerificationMessageTemplate, UsernameAttributes]].`

According to the documentation, these properties should be [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html#API_CreateUserPool_RequestSyntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those properties are supported at this time, the cloudformation template is currently a few revs behind the service.  See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html for the supported options.